# How do I train a new model with my own custom data on tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Please forgive me, I am quite new to Tensorflow so please keep the response as detailed as possible. Thank you very much !!!

My question now is that I have run this script with some parameter

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/data/build_image_data.py

```
# python build_image_data.py --train_directory /Input --validation_directory /validation --output_directory /output --labels_file /labels_file
```

to build image data and get some output, such as
train-00000-of-00002, train-00001-of-00002, validation-00000-of-00002, validation-00001-of-00002

After that, how do I train a new model with above custom data on tensorflow ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolve this stubid question by myself, thanks everyone.

http://blog.twman.org/2016/06/tensorflow.html

```
bazel build inception/build_image_data

bazel-bin/inception/build_image_data   --train_directory="${TRAIN_DIR}"  \
--validation_directory="${VALIDATION_DIR}"   \
--output_directory="${OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}"   \
--labels_file="${LABELS_FILE}"   \
--train_shards=128   \
--validation_shards=24   \
--num_threads=8
```